# Utility functions for processing tweets or texts

Tags: python, strings, functional-programming, twitter

I have 4 functions that process texts or `tweepy.models.Status` object (this object stores text information, author information, retweets & likes information of a specific tweet).

The first function is `filter_unique`, which is used to exclude duplicate tweets from a list of tweets. The result is a `generator`.

The function `clean_text`, is used to remove punctuations, undefined characters, and whitespaces from a string.

The function `split_texts` has two inputs, the list of tweets/strings and the mode of the splits (`naive=True` means it only use `text.split()`, if set to `False` then it will clean the text first before splitting)

The function `total_rts` calculates the total number of retweets. `string_inclusion='word'` means that it will calculate the total retweets of tweets that contain `'word'`.

Question: How to make this module more efficient, and perhaps advanced?

We can use the sample tweets [`testfile.npy`](https://github.com/anbarief/statistweepy/blob/master/samples/testfile.npy) which contains objects `tweepy.models.Status`.

---

```
import tweepy
import string

def filter_unique(tweets):

    uniques = set()

    for tweet in tweets:

        if not isinstance(tweet, tweepy.Status):
            raise TypeError('Each element must be of tweepy.Status object')

        try:
            tweet = tweet.retweeted_status
        except:
            pass

        if tweet.id not in uniques:

            uniques.add(tweet.id)

            yield tweet

def clean_text(text):

    punct = string.punctuation
    printable = string.printable
    whitespace = string.whitespace

    table = text.maketrans({key: None for key in printable})
    undef = set(text.translate(table))

    table = text.maketrans({key: None for key in undef})
    removed_undef = text.translate(table)

    table = text.maketrans({key: None for key in punct})
    cleaned = removed_undef.translate(table)

    table = text.maketrans({key: ' ' for key in whitespace})
    cleaned = cleaned.translate(table)

    return cleaned

def split_texts(texts, naive):

    if naive:
        for text in texts:
            yield text.split()
    else:
        for text in texts:
            yield clean_text(text).split()

def total_rts(tweets, string_inclusion = False, naive = True):

    result = 0

    if not string_inclusion :

        result = sum([tweet.retweet_count for tweet in tweets]);

    else:

        if naive:
            try:
                result = sum([tweet.retweet_count for tweet in tweets if string_inclusion in tweet.full_text.split()])
            except:
                result = sum([tweet.retweet_count for tweet in tweets if string_inclusion in tweet.text.split()])
        else:
            try:
                result = sum([tweet.retweet_count for tweet in tweets if string_inclusion in clean_text(tweet.full_text).split()])
            except:
                result = sum([tweet.retweet_count for tweet in tweets if string_inclusion in clean_text(tweet.text).split()])

    return result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two bare `except`. Avoid doing that so it is:

1. easier to understand what kind of errors you are expecting (it seems both try to catch `AttributeError`s but it is not entirely clear);
2. less error prone as you won't act on exceptions you didn't anticipate (such as `MemoryError` or `KeyboardInterrupt`).

---

The way you handle the `naive` argument in `split_text` and `total_rts` makes for duplicated code. You can take advantage of generator functions or generators to prepare your data depending on the argument and then write the computation once. In your case, `map` can go a long way into preparing your data before processing without actually computing anything before the last moment:

```
import operator


def split_texts(texts, naive):
    if not naive:
        texts = map(clean_text, texts)
    yield from map(str.split, texts)


def total_retweets(tweets, string_inclusion=False, naive=True):
    if not string_inclusion:
        return sum(tweet.retweet_count for tweet in tweets)

    def filtered_retweets(text_attribute):
        texts = map(operator.attrgetter(text_attribute), tweets)
        if not naive:
            texts = map(clean_text, texts)
        texts = map(str.split, texts)

        return sum(tweet.retweet_count for tweet, text in zip(tweets, texts) if string_inclusion in text)

    try:
        return filtered_retweets('full_text')
    except AttributeError:
        return filtered_retweets('text')
```

Answer (score 3):

A few obligatory [PEP-8 rules](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

- Imports should be grouped in the following order:

  1. standard library imports
  2. related third party imports
  3. local application/library specific imports
- Use blank lines in functions, sparingly, to indicate logical sections.
- Two blank lines between the import statements and other code.
- Two blank lines between each function.
- Don't use spaces around the `=` sign when used to indicate a keyword argument or a default parameter value.

If this is written for python-3.x, I'd also suggest going for [Type Hinting](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/).

---

In the `split_texts` definition, I'd suggest having `naive=False` as the default (or `naive=True`) depending on the more obvious choice of the two.

---

In the function `total_rts` (could be renamed to `total_retweets`), you can avoid one entire level of nesting by returning early in the first `if not string_inclusion` clause.

---

The function `clean_text` makes several transition tables, which could be extracted out of the function and made a constant. More importantly, what I understood from the definition, I think you're (in order):

1. cleaning the text of all printable characters
2. cleaning the text of all characters leftover from step 1
3. cleaning all punctuation from result of step 2
4. replacing all kinds of whitespace characters with a single `' '` in the result of step 3.

You can define global transition tables as follows:

```
WHITESPACE = ' ' * len(string.whitespace)
CLEAN_TRANSLATION = str.maketrans(string.whitespace, WHITESPACE, string.punctuation)
```

Alternatively, you can take the `CLEAN_TRANSLATION` inside the `clean_text` function and use the undefined non-printable characters in concatenation to `string.punctuation`. So, the function becomes:

```
def clean_text(text):
    undefined_chars = text.translate(
        str.maketrans({c: None for c in string.printable}))
    cleanup_translation = str.maketrans(
        string.whitespace, WHITESPACE, string.punctuation + undefined_chars)
    return text.translate(cleanup_translation)
```

---

And, most importantly, the description for each function that you've provided in the question, could be converted to [a docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) for each of them.